How to add a button for interaction in the Django admin panel
I want to create a button in test model page in Admin panel that, when clicked, will automatically add a new question based on the test the user selected. Is this possible?
Is there a way to implement this functionality using the existing tools and technology in the Admin panel? If not, what steps or modifications would be required to achieve this feature?


The best way - to override admin template tag submit_row:
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import submit_row, register as admin_modify
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.base import InclusionAdminNode


def custom_submit_row(context):
    """
    Display the row of buttons for delete and save.
    """
    ctx = submit_row(context)
    ctx.update({'show_close': True})
    return ctx


@admin_modify.tag(name='submit_row')
def submit_row_tag(parser, token):
    return InclusionAdminNode(parser, token, func=custom_submit_row, template_name='submit_line.html')

Dont forget to import it somethere, after import it will be registered automatically and you dont need to load it in any template.
If you dont need to do something complex in template context, you can simply override a template submit_line.html

I can't able to find InclusionAdminNode on documentation but only on code. This answer is like a gold. Waiting for this answer to be accepted.

@RajaSimon, You're always welcome! If you want to see more django gems - you can follow my "hidden gems of the django admin panel" series of talks. https://www.youtube.com/@danilovmy
